# WPF C# Posição atual de MDIChild?

Tags: c#, wpf, mdi

Eu tenho implementado um `MDIParent` com 3 filhos.

Eu quero saber onde os filhos estão mas eu não tenho acesso a qualquer propriedade, desde: `child.position` é sempre (0,0).

xaml que tenho:

```
<mdi:MdiContainer Name="mdiParent"/>
```

Código:

```
this.Child.Title = "ChildLoad";
this.Child.Content = this.ChildView;
this.Child.Height = 260;
this.Child.Width = 320;
this.Child.Resizable = false;
this.Child.MaximizeBox = false;
this.mdiParent.Children.Add(Child);
```

Eu posso iniciar o filho em algum ponto, adicionando o seguinte código depois

```
this.Child.Position = new Point(300, 300);
```

Mas após rodar a aplicação, `child.position` é sempre `(0,0)`. Mesmo se eu mover a janela filha.

Como eu consigo a atual posição do filho no `MdiParent`?

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o método `PointToScreen` para saber em que ponto está o `MdiChild`:

```
child.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0))
```

Se mesmo assim tiver dificuldades em obter a posição, pode tentar a partir do `MdiParent`:

```
child.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point());
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, resolveu o problema.

Comment: De nada, ainda bem que pude ajudar! Marque a resposta como correta pf.